# ".NET 7 Way" of File Encryption? RijndaelManaged is obsolete

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, .net-7.0

I am trying to write my own Encrypt/Decrypt methods in a .NET 7 solution (NOT 4.8 or even 6). I know that RijndaelManaged has been the go-to implementation in the past, but Microsoft has now marked that as `Obsolete` so I want to write it "the .NET 7 Way".

While my methods seem to run to completion *most* of the time, I occasionally get exceptions. Worse, none of the files I run my methods on, whether text or binary files (images, executables, etc) get restored back to their original bits properly. All wind up being corrupted in some fashion.

I would be super grateful if someone were to point out what I might have missed (or gotten just plain wrong) in my code.

Here is my Encrypt method:

```
public static void EncryptFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return;

    using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath);

    byte[] salt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32);
    outputStream.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);
    Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);

    int readPosition;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    try
    {
        while ((readPosition = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, readPosition);
        }

        inputStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        cryptoStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

And here is my Decrypt method:

```
public static void DecryptFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return;

    using FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);

    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    inputStream.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);
    Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    using FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create);

    int readPosition;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    try
    {
        while ((readPosition = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readPosition);
        }

        cryptoStream.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        outputStream.Close();
        inputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

I refactored out the `Aes` object which is common to both, into a separate initialization function:

```
private static Aes GetAES(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

    return aes;
}
```

I've experimented with the `PaddingMode`, most notably using `Zeros` and `PKCS7`, but have not gotten it to work for me.

What am I missing and/or what should I do to make this work correctly? I need to be able to encrypt/decrypt any size and/or type of file (in Windows, at least), and to have it work in .NET 7 and beyond.

Thanks in advance for your time.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: @Sir Rufo I've been in this business for 24+ years. There are differing approaches that may be used to encrypt text files and/or passwords in a config file, and this website has numerous such questions to that effect. So I'm making it clear that I need to be able to encrypt/decrypt any file, regardless of it's content and/or file format.

And yes, I read the article already, which does not address the question I had...

...and neither did you, sir.

Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: I am very sorry that I am not in such a long time in that business (wow, I am very impressed) - but I get the information from that link combined some of your code and got a class that can encrypt and decrypt files whithout any loss or corruption of data. But that must be wrong - you are much longer in that game. Sorry, that I could not help you - and I do not bother you again

Comment: You have empty catch blocks in your code. That should almost never be done. You're just throwing away error info that would otherwise help you debug problems. At the very least lof when you encounter errors.

Comment: @mason I'm well aware of how to catch errors and am certainly catching them; I have breakpoints and am at this point single stepping through to the catch block. Most of the time however, I don't get any exceptions. When an error happens, it's typically been "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" and it occurs in my Decrypt method.

I don't understand what is causing this problem nor how to fix it...  which is why I'm here. It doesn't happen in .NET 4.8 when using RijndaelManaged, but the whole point of this post is for me to be able to now do this in .NET 7 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've chosen to use method `GetAES` to create a new instance of [Aes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0), it can't be disposed of within *GetAES* which means a using declaration shouldn't be used.

**GetAES**:

```
private static Aes GetAES(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

    //although 'Aes' implements IDisposable, it can't be disposed of in this method
    //because a reference is being created in the calling method
    //using Aes aes = Aes.Create(); 
    Aes aes = Aes.Create(); 

    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros; 
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);

    return aes;
}
```

In method `EncryptFile`, a using declaration was added `using Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);` and  `readPosition` was renamed to `bytesRead` because the name seemed a bit deceiving - rename it if you want to. I resized the *buffer* array - it can be changed to the desired size. A call to *CryptoStream FlushFinalBlock* method was added. Added code to keep track of total bytes read, as well as, the number of read iterations.

**EncryptFile**:

```
public static void EncryptFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return;

    using FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath);

    byte[] salt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32);
    outputStream.Write(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    using Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    //using ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    //using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);

    long totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4]; //4096

    try
    {
        long i = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            //add
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            Debug.Write($"[{i}] bytesRead: {bytesRead} totalBytesRead: {totalBytesRead}{Environment.NewLine}");

            cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            //increment
            i++;
        }

        inputStream.Close();

        //flush
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        cryptoStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

The changes in method `DecryptFile` are almost identical to those in `EncryptFile`. A using declaration was added `using Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);` and  `readPosition` was renamed to `bytesRead` - rename it if you want to. I resized the *buffer* - it can be changed to the desired size. A call to *Stream Flush* method was added. Added code to keep track of total bytes read, as well as, the number of read iterations.

**DecryptFile**:

```
public static void DecryptFile(string sourcePath, string destinationPath, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) return;

    using FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open);

    byte[] salt = new byte[32];
    inputStream.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

    //'Aes' implements IDisposable
    using Aes aes = GetAES(password, salt);

    using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    //using ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    //using CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    using FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create);

    try
    {
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        //byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4]; //4096

        long i = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            //add
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            Debug.Write($"[{i}] bytesRead: {bytesRead} totalBytesRead: {totalBytesRead}{Environment.NewLine}");

            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            //increment
            i++;
        }

        //flush
        outputStream.Flush();

        //cryptoStream.Close(); //close in finally instead
    }
    catch (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message == "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.")
        {
            //when an invalid password is entered and Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            //one receives this exception
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error: Invalid password.");
            throw new Exception("Invalid password.", ex);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        cryptoStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        inputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

**Additional Resources**:

- [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0)
- [How to choose a padding mode with AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/how-to-choose-a-padding-mode-with-aes)

---

Here's some additional information about *KeySize* and *BlockSize*.

**What are valid values for KeySize and BlockSize**?

If one looks at the documentation for [Aes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0), one sees:

```
public abstract class Aes : System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm
```

If one looks to the left-side of the window one can expand both *Properties* and *Methods*. However, MS doesn't show inherited *Properties* and *Methods* as part of the documentation for the class that inherits them. Therefore, it's necessary to review the documentation for each inherited class. In this case, we'll need to look at the documentation for [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm?view=net-7.0) which is where we'll find the following properties:

- [BlockSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.blocksize?view=net-7.0)
- [FeedbackSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.feedbacksize?view=net-7.0)
- [IV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.iv?view=net-7.0)
- [Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.key?view=net-7.0)
- [KeySize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize?view=net-7.0)
- [LegalBlockSizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes?view=net-7.0)
- [LegalKeySizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes?view=net-7.0)
- [Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode?view=net-7.0)
- [Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding?view=net-7.0)

In both [LegalBlockSizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalblocksizes?view=net-7.0) and [LegalKeySizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.legalkeysizes?view=net-7.0) documentation one will find examples of how to obtain legal block sizes and legal key sizes. Also see [KeySizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.keysizes?view=net-7.0).

Alternatively, one can use the code below:

```
private string GetLegalBlockSizes()
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        foreach (KeySizes ks in aes.LegalBlockSizes)
        {
           //append
            output += $"LegalBlockSizes MinSize: {ks.MinSize} MaxSize: {ks.MaxSize} SkipSize: {ks.SkipSize}{Environment.NewLine}";

            for (int i = ks.MinSize; i <= ks.MaxSize;)
            {
                //1 byte / 8 bits
                //append
                output += $"    {i} bits  =  {i / 8} bytes{Environment.NewLine}";

                if (ks.SkipSize == 0)
                    break;

                //increment
                i += ks.SkipSize;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}

private string GetLegalKeySizes()
{
    string output = string.Empty;

    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        //get legal key sizes
        foreach (KeySizes ks in aes.LegalKeySizes)
        {
            //append
            output += $"LegalKeySizes MinSize: {ks.MinSize} MaxSize: {ks.MaxSize} SkipSize: {ks.SkipSize}{Environment.NewLine}";

            for (int i = ks.MinSize; i <= ks.MaxSize;)
            {
                //1 byte / 8 bits
                //append
                output += $"    {i} bits  =  {i / 8} bytes {Environment.NewLine}";

                if (ks.SkipSize == 0)
                    break;

                //increment
                i += ks.SkipSize;
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Running the code above results in the following output:

```
LegalBlockSizes MinSize: 128 MaxSize: 128 SkipSize: 0
    128 bits  =  16 bytes

LegalKeySizes MinSize: 128 MaxSize: 256 SkipSize: 64
    128 bits  =  16 bytes 
    192 bits  =  24 bytes 
    256 bits  =  32 bytes
```

Also see [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0).

If interested, the source code for [Aes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/aes.cs) and [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs) is publicly available.

Comment: +1 for the time spent - thanks, much appreciated! Will try this code out soon and will let you know how it goes. (I've been out all day today on holiday.)

Comment: BTW, I've been using a 1mb buffer because I'll be encrypting/decrypting large files. I'll probably experiment with the buffer size a bit, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks much! This was just what I was looking for. Appreciate it kindly.  :)

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid Can you please explain why the salt size is related to `Aes.BlockSize`. The salt is only used by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and not by `Aes`.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs#L140) shows it only matters if the salt size is not less than 8

Comment: Who ever will find it usefull in the future I post [my code for this](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/181e4a31bf23b302daf42101714ebe67)