# encrypt a stream on the fly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

In c#, I want to consume an input stream, encrypt in on the fly and upload it to an Azure blob storage.
I've seen that there is an encryption option in BlobServiceClient using ClientSideEncryptionOptions but apparently I can't have the control over the encryption key. I need to generate a symetric encryption key and store it encrypted using a customer public key.
Therefore, the idea is to "hook" the input stream to encrypt on the fly everything that is passing through.

I tried 2 approaches and none of them are working.

I tried this first option: The problem is that inputStream.CopyTo(csEncrypt) consumes the stream and loads it into memory which will prevent to encrypt large files.

```html
    public static MemoryStream EncryptStream(Stream inputStream, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV.
        using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = iv;

        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            // Copy the data to be encrypted from the input stream to the crypto stream.
            inputStream.CopyTo(csEncrypt);
        }

        encryptedStream.Position = 0; // Reset the position of the stream to be read from the beginning
        return encryptedStream;
    }
}
```

I then used another approach, that tried to encrypt "blocks by blocks" by overriding the Stream.Read and encrypt the data passing through it but it does not work (code below is a non workable proof of concept that cannot work because IV is not pushed to the stream).
The problem of this solution is that input stream and output stream do not have the same size and lead to buffer overflows.

```
public class EncryptionStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _innerStream;
    private readonly Encryptor _encryptor;
    private bool _encrypt;

    public EncryptionStream(Stream innerStream, Encryptor encryptor, bool encrypt)
    {
        _innerStream = innerStream;
        _encryptor = encryptor;
        _encrypt=encrypt;   
    }

    public override bool CanRead => _innerStream.CanRead;
    public override bool CanSeek => _innerStream.CanSeek;
    public override bool CanWrite => _innerStream.CanWrite;
    public override long Length => _innerStream.Length;

    public override long Position { get => _innerStream.Position; set => _innerStream.Position=value; }

    public override void Flush() => _innerStream.Flush();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytesRead = _innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
       
            byte[] encryptedData = _encryptor.Encrypt(buffer);
             Array.Copy(encryptedData, 0, buffer, offset, bytesRead);
            return bytesRead;           
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => _innerStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    public override void SetLength(long value) => _innerStream.SetLength(value);
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _innerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);        
}
```

I tried to use it in this way:

```
   using var encryptedStream = new EncryptionStream(stream, _encryptor,true);
   await _rootContainer.UploadBlobAsync(fullPath, encryptedStream);
```

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349600/10024425

Comment: `Array.Copy(encryptedData, 0, buffer, offset, encryptedData.Length); return encryptedData.Length` might also be wise to use some kind of array caching mechanism. What are you actually doing with the stream, maybe there is a way of getting an HTTP write stream that you can write to directly

Comment: I'd strongly recommend wrapping the *output* stream with a crypto stream. You can write the encrypted symmetric key to the unencrypted output stream first, and then use the crypto stream for encrypting the plaintext - possibly by using `copyTo`, but otherwise with a self defined buffer.

Comment: `MemoryStream` should not be needed *at all*.

Comment: Why not use `CryptoStream`? It's way easier than building your own.

Comment: In your first example `CryptoStream csEncrypt` is already what you are asking for? Just don't copy the result into a memory stream. Instead copy it directly to the blob storage api call.

Comment: `.UploadBlobAsync` will read from a stream. So create a `new CryptoStream(inputStream, CryptoStreamMode.Read, ...)` and pass it through.

Comment: @StephenCleary : I feel that if I use solution 1 to push 1 gb file, it will be loaded integrally into memory (usage of memorystream and inputstream.copyto).
I want to avoid that and really stream and encrypt on the fly. I did not yet managed to do that. I believe that the only way is to override the read and encrypt on the fly?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman : not that easy. How to push the IV to the input stream? I'm just turning around, close to the solution but still turning around. When encrypting and pushing to a file, the first thing is to push the IV then push the encrypted flow. Here I can't easily add the IV at the beginning of the stream.

Comment: Because of the API you're given from the blob client, you'll need one stream to provide both parts of data (IV and crypto text). There isn't a built-in "concatenate stream" type so you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution.

Override of the stream:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Utils.Tools
{
    public class EncryptionStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly Stream _innerStream;
        private readonly Encryptor _encryptor;
        private byte[] _residualBuffer = new byte[0];
        private bool _lastCall;
        private bool _isEncrypt;
        public EncryptionStream(Stream innerStream, Encryptor encryptor )
        {
            _innerStream = innerStream;
            _encryptor = encryptor;
            _isEncrypt = encryptor.IsEncrypt;
        }

        public override bool CanRead => _innerStream.CanRead;
        public override bool CanSeek => _innerStream.CanSeek;
        public override bool CanWrite => _innerStream.CanWrite;
        public override long Length => _innerStream.Length;
        public override long Position { get => _innerStream.Position; set => _innerStream.Position=value; }
        public override void Flush() => _innerStream.Flush();
 
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (_lastCall == true)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            int bytesRead = _innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            _lastCall = bytesRead == 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[0];
            if (_isEncrypt == true)
            {
                data = _encryptor.Encrypt(buffer, bytesRead, _lastCall);
            }
            else
            {
                data = _encryptor.Decrypt(buffer, bytesRead, _lastCall);                
            }
            // Create a temporary buffer to hold the residuals plus the new data
            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[_residualBuffer.Length + data.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_residualBuffer, 0, tempBuffer, 0, _residualBuffer.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, tempBuffer, _residualBuffer.Length, data.Length);

            // If the temporary buffer size is greater than count, copy the necessary data to the buffer
            // and save the remaining data to the residual buffer
            if (tempBuffer.Length > count)
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, count);
                _residualBuffer = new byte[tempBuffer.Length - count];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, count, _residualBuffer, 0, _residualBuffer.Length);
                return count;
            }
            else
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                _residualBuffer = new byte[0];
                return tempBuffer.Length;
            }
        }    
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => _innerStream.Seek(offset, origin);
        public override void SetLength(long value) => _innerStream.SetLength(value);
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => _innerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

The encryption layer:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


namespace Utils.Tools
{
    public class Encryptor
    {
        private readonly byte[] _aesKey;
        private CryptoStream _cryptoStream;
        private AesCryptoServiceProvider _aes;
        private MemoryStream _ms;
        private bool _initialized;
        public bool IsEncrypt;
        public Encryptor(byte[] aesKey, bool encrypt)
        {
            _aesKey= aesKey;
            IsEncrypt = encrypt;
            if (encrypt== true)
            {
                InitializeEncryption();
            }           
        }
        public void InitializeEncryption()
        {
            _aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            _aes.Key = _aesKey;          
            _aes.GenerateIV();
            byte[] iv = _aes.IV;
            ICryptoTransform transform = _aes.CreateEncryptor();
            _ms = new MemoryStream();
            _ms.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);
            _cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(_ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);  
        }
        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int bytesCount, bool lastCall)
        {
            if (bytesCount != 0)
            {
                _cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, bytesCount);
            }
            if (lastCall == true)
            {
                _cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            byte[] encrypted = _ms.ToArray();
            _ms.Position = 0;
            _ms.SetLength(0);
            return encrypted;
        }
        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, int bytesCount, bool lastCall)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes;
            if (_initialized == false)
            {
                _aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                _aes.Key = _aesKey;
                byte[] iv = new byte[_aes.BlockSize / 8];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);
                encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedData.Length - iv.Length];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedData, iv.Length, encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
                _aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = _aes.CreateDecryptor();
                _ms = new MemoryStream();
                _cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(_ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                _initialized = true;
                bytesCount -=iv.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                encryptedBytes = encryptedData;
            }
            if (bytesCount != 0)
            {
                _cryptoStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, bytesCount);
            }
            if (lastCall == true)
            {
                _cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            byte[] decrypted = _ms.ToArray();
            _ms.Position = 0;
            _ms.SetLength(0);
            return decrypted;
        }
    }
}
```

And you call it this way:

```
private async Task UploadFile(string fullPath, Stream stream)
    {
        if (_context.BackupSettings.EncryptData == true)
        {
            using var encryptedStream = new EncryptionStream(stream, _encryptor);
            await RetryHelper.RetryOnExceptionAsync(async () =>
            {
                await _rootContainer.UploadBlobAsync(fullPath, encryptedStream);
            }, "UploadEncryptedFile");
        }
        else
        {
            await RetryHelper.RetryOnExceptionAsync(async () =>
            {
                await _rootContainer.UploadBlobAsync(fullPath, stream);
            }, "UploadFile");
        }
    }
```