# Problem with the exception "The input data is not a complete block" in c# when I try to encrypt a file

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I tried to create a program in .Net 7 that encrypts a file, saves it into another file and decrypts the encrypted file. The problem is when it tries to decrypt the encrypted file, it returns the exception: "The input data is not a complete block.". This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original file name");
        string inputfilename = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted file");
        string outputfilename = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypt file name");
        string decrypt = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] key;
        byte[] IV;
        (key,IV)= Encryption(inputfilename, outputfilename);
        Decryption(key, IV,outputfilename,decrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("Is ready!");


    }
    public static (byte[], byte[]) Encryption( string inputfilename, string outputfilename)
    {
        using (var readStream = File.OpenRead(inputfilename))
        using (var createstream = File.OpenWrite(outputfilename))
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(createstream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            readStream.CopyTo(createstream);
            return (aes.Key, aes.IV);
        }
    }
    public static void Decryption (byte[] key, byte[] IV,string inputfile, string outputfile)
    {
        using(var readstream = File.OpenRead(inputfile))
        using(var createstream = File.Create(outputfile))
        using (var aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV= IV;
            using(var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key,aes.IV))
            using (var cstream = new CryptoStream(readstream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                cstream.CopyTo(createstream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix all the problems that I found, but I did not succeed doing it. I would be thankful, if you would find the problem.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349600/10024425 and [Aes Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Try in `Encryption()`: `readStream.CopyTo(cstream)`