# Encryption file transfer application - Padding is invalid

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption

So, I am making an encrypted file transfer program. I exchange keys using DH and encrypt files using AES.. It now sends the file properly, but when I check the recived file (for example I used a 450 line sql file), the last line is all gibberish.. I think it has to do something with the fact that Im reading chunks of 4096 bytes. I tried doing the unpadding manually but still nothing..

````
namespace FileTransfer
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        int PORT = 1234;
        private ECDiffieHellmanCng senderKey;
        private ECDiffieHellmanCng receiverKey;
        private byte[] iv;
        private const int blockSize = 128;
        private const int bufferSize = 4096;
        private Aes aes;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            senderKey = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(256);
            receiverKey = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(256);    

        }

        private void AppendStatus(string status)
        {
            statusTextBox.AppendText(status + Environment.NewLine);
            statusTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
        }

        private void SendClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] senderHashKey = null;

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect("localhost", PORT);

            AppendStatus("Connected to the server.");

            byte[] publicKeyBytes = senderKey.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(publicKeyBytes, 0, publicKeyBytes.Length);

            AppendStatus("Sent public key to the receiver.");

            byte[] receiverPublicKeyBytes = new byte[senderKey.PublicKey.ToByteArray().Length];
            tcpClient.GetStream().Read(receiverPublicKeyBytes, 0, receiverPublicKeyBytes.Length);
            ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey receiverPublicKey = ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(receiverPublicKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

            byte[] sharedSecret = senderKey.DeriveKeyMaterial(receiverPublicKey);

            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                senderHashKey = sha256.ComputeHash(sharedSecret);
            }

            aes=Aes.Create();
            iv = aes.IV;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.BlockSize = blockSize;
            aes.Key = senderHashKey;
            aes.Mode= CipherMode.CBC;

            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string fileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            SendFileInfo(tcpClient.GetStream(), fileName, fileType);


            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int bytesRead;

                    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                    //Debug.WriteLine($"Original data: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)}\n");


                    // Encrypt the data block
                    byte[] encryptedData = EncryptData(buffer, senderHashKey, iv);

                    //Debug.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {BitConverter.ToString(encryptedData)}\n");
                    // Send the encrypted data
                    tcpClient.GetStream().Write(encryptedData, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            tcpClient.Close();

            AppendStatus("File sent successfully.");
        }

        private void ReceiveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] receiverHashKey = null;

            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, PORT);
            tcpListener.Start();

            AppendStatus("Waiting for connection...");

            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            AppendStatus("Connection accepted from " + ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());

            byte[] senderPublicKeyBytes = new byte[receiverKey.PublicKey.ToByteArray().Length];
            tcpClient.GetStream().Read(senderPublicKeyBytes, 0, senderPublicKeyBytes.Length);
            ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey senderPublicKey = ECDiffieHellmanCngPublicKey.FromByteArray(senderPublicKeyBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);

            byte[] publicKeyBytes = receiverKey.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
            tcpClient.GetStream().Write(publicKeyBytes, 0, publicKeyBytes.Length);
            AppendStatus("Sent public key to the sender.");

            byte[] sharedSecret = receiverKey.DeriveKeyMaterial(senderPublicKey);

            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                receiverHashKey = sha256.ComputeHash(sharedSecret);
            }

            byte[] receivedIV = new byte[16];
            tcpClient.GetStream().Read(receivedIV, 0, receivedIV.Length);

            iv = receivedIV;
            AppendStatus("IV: " + BitConverter.ToString(iv));

            aes=Aes.Create();
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            aes.BlockSize = blockSize;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Key = receiverHashKey;

            FileInfo fileInfo = ReceiveFileInfo(tcpClient.GetStream());

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead;
                try
                {
                    while ((bytesRead = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        //Debug.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {BitConverter.ToString(buffer)}\n");
                        byte[] decryptedData = DecryptData(buffer, receiverHashKey, iv);
                        //decryptedData = RemoveZerosPadding(decryptedData);
                        //Debug.WriteLine($"Decrypted data: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData)}\n");

                        // Only write the actual number of decrypted bytes to the file
                        fileStream.Write(decryptedData, 0, bytesRead);

                        AppendStatus($"Bytes read: {bytesRead}, Decrypted data length: {decryptedData.Length}");

                        // Check if the last read was less than the buffer size
                        
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    AppendStatus($"Error reading or decrypting data: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }

        /*private byte[] RemoveZerosPadding(byte[] data)
        {
            int paddingLength = 0;

            // Find the index of the last non-zero byte
            for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (data[i] == 0)
                {
                    paddingLength++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Calculate the length of data without padding
            int unpaddedLength = data.Length - paddingLength;

            // Create a new array with the unpadded data
            byte[] unpaddedData = new byte[unpaddedLength];
            Array.Copy(data, unpaddedData, unpaddedLength);

            return unpaddedData;
        }*/

        private byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private byte[] DecryptData(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }

                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }


        private void BrowseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                filePath=openFileDialog.FileName;
                selected_file.Text="Selected file: " + filePath;
            }
        }

        private void SendFileInfo(NetworkStream stream, string fileName, string fileType)
        {
            // Send the file name length
            byte[] fileNameLengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length);
            stream.Write(fileNameLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));

            // Send the file name
            byte[] fileNameBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            stream.Write(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameBytes.Length);
        }

        private FileInfo ReceiveFileInfo(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();

            // Receive the file name length
            byte[] fileNameLengthBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            stream.Read(fileNameLengthBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
            int fileNameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileNameLengthBytes, 0);

            // Receive the file name
            byte[] fileNameBytes = new byte[fileNameLength];
            stream.Read(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameLength);
            fileInfo.FileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileNameBytes);

            return fileInfo;
        }
    }
    public class FileInfo
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
}

```

I think this is because I read 1MB chunks, but file isnt always an even number of chunks (1MB, 2MB etc). But I need the chunk size to always be 1MB, how could I solve this?
````

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349600/10024425

Comment: You are assuming that read returns exactly as many bytes as you requested, but NetworkStream.Read() doesn't make that guarantee. Read returns the number of bytes it actually reads, and you should loop until you receive the number of bytes you expect.

Comment: Use `ReadExactly` maybe?

Comment: Also the padding is implemented inconsistently. As an example, consider the case `bytesRead` equals `chunkSize`: Due to the enabled PKCS#7 padding, `encryptedData` has the size `chunkSize + 16`, but only `bytesRead` are written, i.e. the padding block is truncated. When receiving, however, each chunk is tried to be unpadded, which leads to a padding error due to the missing padding block. It would make sense to disable padding apart from the last chunk (for sending and receiving). Another optimization would be to use the last block of the previous ciphertext chunk as IV.

Comment: Also, do you know what a man in the middle attack is? DH without authentication is not secure against active attacks (and if an adversary can perform a passive attack it is very likely that active attacks are easy as well, see WiFi security for instance).

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question. It will make it impossible for others to see how the answer relates to the question. If you have other questions then ask them in the comments (if they are relatively small followup questions) or ask a new one. Rereading the comments and answers could also help; the fact that the buffer handling was suspicious should give a lot of hints to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The big question is: why do you need chunks at all?

The current code is not just incorrect, it is also insecure as you're reusing the IV for each chunk.

The [`CryptoStream` already pad automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?view=net-8.0#remarks) when it gets closed. There is no reason to do that separately:

> Calling the `Close` method will call `FlushFinalBlock`. If you do not call `Close`, call `FlushFinalBlock` to complete flushing the buffer. Call `FlushFinalBlock` only when all stream activity is complete.

To me it is already a mystery why it is there at all: I guess that helps if resource management isn't performed. However, if you use `using` then `Dispose` will call `Close` and that will call `FlushFinalBlock`.

Finally, if you read the Mickeysoft documentation **very** carefully you will find that in the *exception handling part* of `FlushFinalBlock` it reads that an exception is thrown when:

> The final block has already been transformed.

So of course it will call [`ICryptoTransform#TransformFinalBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformfinalblock?view=net-8.0) of the underlying encryptor or decryptor.

Now that doesn't explicitly tell you it pads or unpads, but at this point I give up in the badly designed maze that is the Mickeysoft documentation.

---

Furthermore, you can forgo all the "chunking" by using [`Stream.CopyTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-8.0#system-io-stream-copyto(system-io-stream)) and giving the right buffer size there. Disadvantage is that they may forget to clear the buffer after use, which could be a reason to use a buffer yourself - assuming that you clear it yourself after the bytes have been copied of course.

Regardless, the plaintext only needs to be padded once, you don't have to do that yourself. The ciphertext should always be the same given the same key, IV and plaintext *regardless of the buffer size*.

"Chunks" are only required if you want to do something special with the various chuncks, e.g. you might want to have MAC-generated authentication tag for specific chunks so you can authenticate the chunks separate. There doesn't seem to be any hint for such a use case in your code.

Comment: So, I fixed most of it.. It now sends the file properly, but when I check the recived file (for example I used a 450 line sql file), the last line is all gibberish.. I think it has to do something with the fact that Im reading chunks of 4096 bytes, but the last chunk is all gibberish. I tried doing the unpadding manually but still nothing.. I updated the above code, I appreciate all the help

Comment: What probably happens is that you use a buffer that is usually fully filled, but which is now partially filled. You need to take care of the return values of any calls to `Read`. Instead of `PaddingMode.Zeros` use PKCS#7 - no manual padding / unpadding should be required. If everything goes right you should end up with a lot less code...