Converting a binary file contents to their hex code string in VB.NET
So I am making an image obfuscator which will help save the privacy of my images on a shared computer. The idea is to read the contents of the image, convert the bytes array into their corresponding ANSI array, convert the ANSI (decimal) to hex and finally save that hex code array in a new file. Then I can simply delete the original file.
What I have come up with, so far, is this:
Dim scr_filename As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\mypic.jpg"

Dim fdata = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(scr_filename)

        Dim res As String = "", fstr As String, num As Integer

        fstr = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fdata)

        For i As Integer = 0 To (fstr.Length - 1)
            num = Asc(fstr.Substring(i, 1))
            res += num.ToString + " "
        Next
        MsgBox(res)

The issue with this code is that it takes about 10 seconds to convert a 20 kb file to ANSI and beyond 20 kb, it simply freezes and I never get any output at all. Please also note that so far this is only converting bytes into their ANSI values and not converting the ANSI into their corresponding hex code.
Is there any method to optimize this code so as to be able to convert up to 400-500 kb files? Many thanks.

That's probably the worst idea possible. Why don't you encrypt the file instead? Example here

I am making an image obfuscator which will help save the privacy of my images on a shared computer: The standard is to NOT store any personal data on a shared computer - it's one of the reasons that USB flash drives exist.

@Jimi: According to TripleDES Class: A newer symmetric encryption algorithm, Advanced Encryption Standard (AES), is available. Consider using the Aes class and its derived classes instead of the TripleDES class (in the pink box). If one is interested in AES encryption the following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349600/10024425 (Disclaimer: I wrote the post.)

@Itallmakescents Sure, that's also suggested (the same thing) in the post I've linked (the only one related to encryption I've written in VB.NET :). What matter is using a symmetric encryption, not asymmetric (for this)

@Itallmakescents it is a computer in my home that everybody uses. It is not a workplace computer. Now, I don't mean that I am planning to obfuscate my naked pictures or something. It is just that I don't want my sister to show my shorts, swimming, campfire and other such photos to her friends who come here facepalm

@Jimi I know basic encryption principles. Long time ago, I built a multiple subscription cipher and transposition cipher program in VB6. I am very new to vb.net and I am doing it as a challenge. Otherwise I could simply put all those images in an archive, password lock it and then email it to myself. That would only be a ~25-30 MB file. But taking that route, I would learn nothing new in vb.net, which would be an admission of defeat.

If you're challenging yourself on something, my suggestion is picking something that is worthwhile and has actually meaning, also not prone to undebuggable errors -- Further suggestions: drop VB6 stuff entirely (as MsgBox(), or Asc()). Possibly also stuff like My.Computer.FileSystem and use the .NET provided namespaces (as System.IO.File) -- Drop any virtual knowledge of what actually ANSI is. At best, it's a multi-byte representation tightly coupled with the local encoding. Despite the name, Windows code-pages don't comply with ANSI / ISO standards. Think Unicode instead

Windows has the ability to have multiple user accounts on a single computer and setting security permissions can prevent other users from accessing files.

The Asc function inside a loop can be slow when processing large amounts of data.
You don't need to convert bytes to characters and then to ANSI values, just process the bytes directly.
Dim scr_filename As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop + "\mypic.jpg"

Dim fileBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(scr_filename)

Dim hexString As String = String.Join("", fileBytes.Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))

File.WriteAllText("path_to_your_output_file.txt", hexString)


Wow. Just ... wow! Elegant solution!

I had this code to produce output of a file in hex.  Modified for your use.
    Const perLine As Integer = 8
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Using fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead("input filename here")
        Using br As New IO.BinaryReader(fs)
            Do Until fs.Position = fs.Length
                Dim byt As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                sb.Append(byt.ToString("X2").PadLeft(2, "0"c))
                ' sb.Append(" ")
                count += 1
                If count = perLine Then
                    'sb.AppendLine()
                    count = 0
                End If
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    IO.File.WriteAllText("output filename here", sb.ToString)

